# Do other languages have similar ArrayAccess features as PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, programming-languages

Long story short, there is a PHP feature called ArrayAccess which allows you to overload the `[]` operator (among other things I think) for your class, so you could have a custom class `MyClass implements ArrayAccess` of which `$myVariable` is an Instance, and do stuff like

`$myVariable[]=6;`

or  `$someVar=$myVariable[78];`

After you've defined what it'll behave like.

I find this feature rather rather elegant and useful and would like to know **whether this is possible in other programming languages**.

Thank you!

Comment: Any proper OO language should allow you to overload `[]` either directly or by subclassing Array.  The details will depend on the specific language.  Non-fully OO languages may also provide such features; for example, in Perl you can use tied arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ supports this in operator overloading.

Most .Net languages support this in indexers.

Comment: [No](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_Overloading#Timeline_of_operator_overloading).

Answer (score 1):

**Python** supports it too, by implementing the ["magic" methods `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).

With them you can even support slicing like `obj[i:j]`.